# How can I reposition a nav bar from the side to the center with enlarged font with just CSS flexbox?

Tags: html, css

I'm supposed to only use flexbox to move things around when the page width changes to below certain threshold. The before and after page layouts are supposed to look like this below: [image: page before changing width][image: page after lowering width below 1000px]   I have no idea how this is done and this assignment is one that comes before learning grid and media-query so I think I'm really not supposed to use those.

My code is as follows (there are no lines that have anything to do with repositioning the nav bar because I don't know what properties are to be used for that purpose, so it's basically just a generic display of the title, the nav bar, the passages and the footer):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <style>
      .content {
        margin: 0 auto;
        min-width: 1000px;
      }
      .flex {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
      }
      a {
        color: red;
      }
      article {
        margin-left: 200px;
      }
      body {
        font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
      }
      footer {
        color: #888888;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin-left: 100px;
      }
      header {
        font-size: 60px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      nav {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-left: 100px;
        position: absolute;
      }
    </style>
    <title>Responsive Layout</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <header>My Responsive Layout</header>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="flex">
          <nav>
            <a href="">Home</a>
            <a href="">About Us</a>
            <a href="">Contact Us</a>
          </nav>
          <article>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque
              vel felis id quam sodales volutpat non vitae tellus. Integer eu
              diam auctor, ultrices lorem id, volutpat nisi. Sed pretium, augue
              nec elementum feugiat, neque magna ultrices nulla, at venenatis
              augue magna at ligula. Nunc euismod, turpis sed eleifend commodo,
              tellus elit lacinia ipsum, eu scelerisque tortor neque id mauris.
              Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
              Morbi vitae elit id mi molestie laoreet. Vivamus tempor, magna vel
              iaculis aliquet, dolor nulla rhoncus turpis, in consequat nisi
              tortor at enim. Sed faucibus magna erat, efficitur facilisis
              mauris ornare nec.
            </p>
            <p>
              Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
              malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Morbi orci nunc, blandit et
              velit non, luctus elementum sapien. Donec arcu purus, consequat
              quis diam quis, pretium tempus urna. Morbi efficitur mollis
              mattis. Duis eu sodales lorem. Etiam vel fermentum lacus. Nunc
              fermentum erat et aliquet dapibus. Integer pharetra imperdiet
              vestibulum. Pellentesque varius magna a lorem tristique efficitur.
              Praesent facilisis congue nibh sed efficitur. Nullam arcu ligula,
              eleifend ut lectus sit amet, sodales rutrum ex. Proin ultricies
              vulputate velit vitae porttitor.
            </p>
            <p>
              Ut ultrices sollicitudin arcu id viverra. In nec varius orci.
              Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
              malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam euismod urna non augue
              tincidunt aliquet. Suspendisse pretium dui vitae libero euismod
              porttitor. Sed tristique pulvinar interdum. Praesent vestibulum ac
              orci a consequat. Etiam bibendum sagittis viverra. Vestibulum quis
              mi tortor. Nulla bibendum nunc et metus faucibus aliquet.
            </p>
          </article>
        </div>
        <footer>&copy; My Special Layout Crew</footer>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Please teach me how it's done with flexbox alone if possible. Thanks much!

Comment: share your html + css code please also!

Comment: OP - please update with your current HTML and CSS. It is hard to help without them. :)

Comment: why dont you use media queries!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with the current CSS:

1. `nav` doesn't need `position: absolute`;
2. Following (1) above, explicit margins for `nav` and `article` are not needed either
3. Not using `justify-content` and `flex-wrap` attributes makes your markup arrangement hacky

The following should give you an idea, adjust values per your need.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <style>
      .content {
        margin: 0 auto;
        min-width: 1000px;
      }
      .flex {
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        max-width: 800px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      a {
        color: red;
      }
      article {
        min-width: 800px;
      }
      body {
        font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
      }
      footer {
        color: #888888;
        font-size: 14px;
        margin-left: 100px;
      }
      header {
        font-size: 60px;
        text-align: center;
      }
      nav {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        min-width: 100px;
      }
    </style>
    <title>Responsive Layout</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <header>My Responsive Layout</header>
      <div class="content">
        <div class="flex">
          <nav>
            <a href="">Home</a>
            <a href="">About Us</a>
            <a href="">Contact Us</a>
          </nav>
          <article>
            <p>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque
              vel felis id quam sodales volutpat non vitae tellus. Integer eu
              diam auctor, ultrices lorem id, volutpat nisi. Sed pretium, augue
              nec elementum feugiat, neque magna ultrices nulla, at venenatis
              augue magna at ligula. Nunc euismod, turpis sed eleifend commodo,
              tellus elit lacinia ipsum, eu scelerisque tortor neque id mauris.
              Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
              Morbi vitae elit id mi molestie laoreet. Vivamus tempor, magna vel
              iaculis aliquet, dolor nulla rhoncus turpis, in consequat nisi
              tortor at enim. Sed faucibus magna erat, efficitur facilisis
              mauris ornare nec.
            </p>
            <p>
              Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
              malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Morbi orci nunc, blandit et
              velit non, luctus elementum sapien. Donec arcu purus, consequat
              quis diam quis, pretium tempus urna. Morbi efficitur mollis
              mattis. Duis eu sodales lorem. Etiam vel fermentum lacus. Nunc
              fermentum erat et aliquet dapibus. Integer pharetra imperdiet
              vestibulum. Pellentesque varius magna a lorem tristique efficitur.
              Praesent facilisis congue nibh sed efficitur. Nullam arcu ligula,
              eleifend ut lectus sit amet, sodales rutrum ex. Proin ultricies
              vulputate velit vitae porttitor.
            </p>
            <p>
              Ut ultrices sollicitudin arcu id viverra. In nec varius orci.
              Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et
              malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam euismod urna non augue
              tincidunt aliquet. Suspendisse pretium dui vitae libero euismod
              porttitor. Sed tristique pulvinar interdum. Praesent vestibulum ac
              orci a consequat. Etiam bibendum sagittis viverra. Vestibulum quis
              mi tortor. Nulla bibendum nunc et metus faucibus aliquet.
            </p>
          </article>
        </div>
        <footer>&copy; My Special Layout Crew</footer>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now the page looks like when the page changes its width to less than 1000px, but I still don't know how to make this change a transition from the nav bar being at the left side to moving to the center. I also forgot to mention that the footer and the passages (stays indented) stay the same position and the former moves to the middle of the page when the page width is below 1000px.

Comment: You'll need to modify the widths to achieve stacking at whatever the breakpoint is. `flex-wrap` and `min-width` accomplish that.